# Using Sesame 2 and MySQL in my Java Class

Tags: java, mysql, sesame, rdfstore

It's my first time with Sesame 2 so please be kind. It could be a stupid question but I can't find documentation about how to use Sesame 2 and a mysql store.
I've created one using the

```
create mysql.
```

command in the Open-rdf console but now I do not know how to use it in Java. The official documentation presents some example but it's about the Native or Memory repository.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the sesame API: http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame/users/ch07.html
Connect to the server and execute a SeRQL query or use the API to search by node.

Comment: Can you explain this deeper? Basically I should run the console, connect to my sesame server, then create the mysql store and the use HTTPRepository? Is that it?

Comment: Yes, the link I provided you should be clear enough. If you have a specific problem, please be more specific